# Is free WiFi available in a night train from Istanbul to Sofia?

Tags: trains, istanbul, wifi, night-transport, sofia

I wonder whether a night train from Istanbul to Sofia ([a train that leaves at 22:40 and arrives at 8:45](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Istanbul.htm)) offers WiFi.

Also, if it is available, does the WiFi work decently? (Since on these types of trains, even though they offer WiFi, it is practically useless and I could not connect in the first place...).

Comment: @dda The reason it should be WiFi instead of Wi-Fi...?

Comment: Another solution can be renting a pocket wifi it's not free but when comparing it with other solutions it's really efficient to use and affordable. You can use it both in Istanbul and Sofia. I used one and it was good for me.

Comment: I think the original (Wi-Fi) was correct as that is the trademark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If things are not changed in last years you will travel in an old standard coach without sockets or Wi-fi (and no restaurant coach). Please pay attention, because trains don't leave anymore from Istanbul but from Halkali (Istanbul suburbs).

Comment: There's indeed no Wifi, but there are two types of Trains: old Bulgarian couchette cars and new Turkish couchette/sleeper cars. If booking a 6-berth couchette, you'll get the old Train, and if booking a 4-berth couchette or sleeper, you'll get the new train